# R: Is it possible to estimate the poisson noise?

Tags: r, modeling, noise, poisson-distribution

I have a dataset of many discrete counts (RNAseq read counts per base), which contain both real signals and background noise. The noise is random, and should be poisson distributed.

What I would like to do is to subtract (or set a threshold for) a baseline that roughly equals the mean of the noise + a CI, based on the data. However, if I just take the mean from the entire data, I include the signal as well.

Is there a way to somehow estimate the noise mean, given that one already assumes there is a random noise + specific signal peak distribution in the data? I know there are specific peak calling algorithms, but for my purposes I try to have an estimate of the baseline as well.

Comment: This sounds more like a statistics question...

Comment: do you suggest the question is inappropriate? I'm new to the site so I'm not quite familiar with it. In the end I am looking for something that I could use in R. I am also not enough of a statistician to know whether or not the task I describe is 'solvable'.

Comment: Perhaps, fit a finite mixture model with one component for the signal and one for the noise.  I think this is a standard problem (and solution) in astrophysics.

Comment: Agreed that the appropriate model for this problem is a mixture model in which one component is the baseline noise.